# Lifetime ISA Eligibility

Tags: united-kingdom, limited-liability-company, isa

I am a director of a Limited company (SPV) which owns an investment property on a Limited Company Buy to Let. I am one of four directors, other directors are parents and sibling. I don't own a residential property.

Am I eligible for a Lifetime ISA?

Comment: Good question so I upvoted it! I thought the answer to this would be clear cut but after a bit of research I don't think the HMRC wording is definitive either way. The declaration of being a first time buyer (on the form here- wording is the same as the help to buy ISA: https://www.helptobuy.gov.uk/documents/2015/12/eligibility-of-ftbs.pdf/) in this case seems to hinge on whether your ownership interest in the investment property "entitles you to possess or occupy" it. I suspect as an individual director (of 4) it doesn't, but that's just my layman opinion...

Comment: ... this scenario will probably end up being tested in some kind of legal case! Because my gut feel is there could end up being a loophole of some sort here for someone (probably not in your specific circumstances though). I can think of scenarios where it could happen but I won't write them out!

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you can. As you don't own the SPV outright you probably can.

***If you owned a company or had a trust that owned residential property that you are (or were) able to live in, you're also not considered a first-time buyer.***

[SOURCE](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/savings/lifetime-isas/)